# ntop-ng installation, missing package

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm trying to install ntop-ng on Ubuntu 14.04 via the [official guide](http://www.nmon.net/apt-stable/).
However, I have the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nbox : Depends: tshark but it is not going to be installed
```

If I try to install tshark, it returns

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tshark : Depends: wireshark-common (= 1.10.6-1) but 1.11.3+svn54293-0ubuntu1~raring1~ppa0 is to be installed.
```

What can I do to install this software?

EDIT: It seems that the problem is with `wireshark-common`.

Indeed

```
$>dpkg -l | grep wireshark-common
ii  wireshark-common                                                     1.11.3+svn54293-0ubuntu1~raring1~ppa0               amd64        network traffic analyser (common files)
```

This name is a bit suspicious to me: why raring? Maybe it's just a legacy of the old Ubuntu system I have installed? I'll try with a purge/reinstall.

Comment: @markkirby I followed the official guide for Ubuntu 14.04; every other guide out there is pretty much a copy/paste of that guide.
Regarding `wireshark-common`, it is already installed on my system. However, I found a few problems with it; I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem forcing a reinstall of `wireshark-common` package.
Steps:

1. `sudo apt-get purge --remove wireshark-common`
2. `sudo apt-get install wireshark-common nbox`